# rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncontroller

I've got the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/favicon.ico")
```

I want to show error404 page for links that are not existing.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 62):

In `application_controller.rb` add the following:

```
  # You want to get exceptions in development, but not in production.
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: -> { render_404  }
  end

  def render_404
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end
```

I usually also rescue following exceptions, but that's up to you:

```
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: -> { render_404  }
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,        with: -> { render_404  }
```

Create the errors controller:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def error_404
    render 'errors/not_found'
  end
end
```

Then in `routes.rb`

```
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    # having created corresponding controller and action
    get '*path', to: 'errors#error_404', via: :all
  end
```

And the last thing is to create `not_found.html.haml` (or whatever template engine you use) under `/views/errors/`:

```
  %span 404
  %br
  Page Not Found
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 4.2.5.  I'm guessing that's because the exception is raised by ActionDispatch before any controller code is run.

Comment: @depquid I wrote it in the times of Rails 4.0.x, but have just tested it with Rails 4.2.5 - I suppose you did not add route and did not create the `errors_controller.rb` :) If that is the case - please be sure to retract the downvote, unless you have more reasons to leave it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't set up the route correctly.  But why have, `rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: -> { render_404  }` if you're routing directly to the action?

Comment: If you need to catch this before any Controller code is run (i.e. on the Routes level), see @misu's answer below for adding `match '*path' => 'errors#error_404', via: :all`.

Comment: How can you get a `ActionController::RoutingError` when you have a path that matches everything (`get '*path', to: 'errors#error_404', via: :all`) ?

Answer (score 10):

@Andrey Deineko, your solution seems to work only for the `RoutingError`s raised manually inside a conrtoller. If I try it with the url `my_app/not_existing_path`, I still get the standard error message.

I guess this is because the application doesn't even reach the controllers, since Rails raises the error before.

The [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359088/custom-error-handling-with-rails-4-0#20508445) that solved the problem for me was to add the following line at the **end** of the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # existing paths
  match '*path' => 'errors#error_404', via: :all
end
```

to catch all not predefined requests.

Then in the ErrorsController you can use `respond_to` to serve html, json... requests:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def error_404
    @requested_path = request.path
    repond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: {routing_error: @requested_path} }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: could you explain `@requested_path = request.path` and its corresponding call `format.json { render json: {routing_error: @requested_path} }`?

Comment: I've just used `@requested_path` in the template (error_404.html.haml). As for the json, if I'm sure I don't want a full page returned, for example by ajax,  I can ask for json returned, and get the error message

Comment: @misu this works perfect, your trick of adding this in the `config/routes.rb` file was the key

Answer (score 1):

Copying **favicon image** in `app/assets/images` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7 (2023)

1. config/routes.rb

   Rails.application.routes.draw do

   match '*path' => 'errors#error_404', via: :all

   end
2. controllers/errors_controller.rb

   class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

   def error_404

   ```
    render template: 'pages/not_found', status: 404
   ```

   end

   end
3. pages/not_found.html.erb

Error 404

Page not found

... but you are losing all active_storage images!!!