# rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to rescue from `ActionController::RoutingError` and I can't get it to work. I tried almost everything that I could find online, including [rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841377/rescue-from-actioncontrollerroutingerror-in-rails4). I have an errors controller and error pages. I got to work cancan `access denied` and `RecordNotFound`, but I can solve the `RoutingError`.

For cancan I use this inside `application_controller.rb`

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do
    render template: 'errors/error_403', status: 403
  end
```

and I have this in my routes:

```
match "/404", to: "errors#error_404", via: :all
```

If I do the same thing for `RoutingError` it won't work.

I've also tried `match '*path', :to => "errors#error_404"` but I get erors.

How can I solve this?

Edit: If I do the same thing for `RoutingError` as for access denied:

```
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do
       render template: 'errors/error_404', status: 404
    end
```

it won't work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `ActionController::RoutingError` is raised when Rails tries to match the request with a route. This happens before Rails even initializes a controller - thus your ApplicationController never has a chance to rescue the exception.

Instead the Rails default `exceptions_app` kicks in - note that this is an app in the Rack sense - it takes a ENV hash with a request and returns a response - in this case the static `/public/404.html` file.

What you can do is have your Rails app handle rendering the error pages dynamically instead:

```
# config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes # a Rack Application

# config/routes.rb
match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found", :via => :all
match "/500", :to => "errors#internal_server_error", :via => :all
```

You would then setup a specific controller to handle the error pages - don't do this in your ApplicationController class as you would be adding a `not_found` and `internal_server_error` method to all your controllers!

```
class ErrorsController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def not_found
    render(status: 404)
  end

  def internal_server_error
    render(status: 500)
  end
end
```

Code borrowed from [Matt Brictson: Dynamic Rails Error Pages](https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages) - read it for the full rundown.

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborate answer. I understand it better now.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation that `ActionController::RoutingError` will raise before Rails actually calls the application. I try to follow your suggestion above but I still got `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/xxxx")` when I try to go to like `localhost:3000/xxxx`. May be I miss something ?

Comment: My bad. I need to tell Rails to render the error page by add this line `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` in `config/environment/development.rb`. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: this solution is not working in production mode of rails with nginx and passenger, in ruby 2.3.8

Answer (score 23):

There is a better way to do it:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match '*unmatched', to: 'application#route_not_found', via: :all
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def route_not_found
    render file: Rails.public_path.join('404.html'), status: :not_found, layout: false
  end
end
```

To test locally, set the following and restart server.

config/development.rb

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Tested with Rails 6.

Comment: I just tested this in Rails 7 and changing the development config was enough