# How to use RoutingError ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working implement vanity URLs based on the tutorial here: https://wesleyluyten.com/writing/vanity-urls-for-multiple-controllers-in-rails

To make vanity URLs work I need to use a rack router like so:

```
class SlugRouter
  def self.to(action)
    new(action)
  end
  def initialize(action)
    @action = action
  end
  def call(env)
    params = env['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters']
    params[:action] = @action

    sluggable = Slug.where('lower(url) = ?', params[:slug].downcase).first
    model = sluggable.try(:sluggable_type)
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') if !model

    controller = [model.pluralize.camelize,'Controller'].join
    params[:controller] = model.pluralize.downcase
    controller.constantize.action(params[:action]).call(env)
  end
end
```

The problem is with `raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') if !model` this is not gracefully handling routing errors. How can I gracefully handle routing error by redirecting to root w a flash message vs what is happening now is rails is showing an error page w

```
ActionController::RoutingError (Not Found):
lib/slug_router.rb:14:in `call'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Unknown Route' if !model
```

Or:

```
if !model
  params[:controller] = 'index'
  IndexController.action('index').call(env)
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: is it possible inside a class which is not inherited from `ActionController::Base`?

Comment: try the alternate solution I posted

Comment: I tried the alt solution. It did prevent the rails error message but ended up loading the the index with the incorrect URL, this would cause an SEO headache. How can I get it to simply redirect to a url like '/' or '/404' for seo purposes... thanks

Comment: throw the Exception like earlier and handle it like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841377/rescue-from-actioncontrollerroutingerror-in-rails4