# How to ignore/supress a specific type of exception (ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord) across my code base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, exception

I am trying to create a read only version of my application and have monkey patched ActiveRecord::Base so that it returns `true` for `readonly?` across all models:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def readonly?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

This results in `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` exceptions being raised wherever I am trying to write to the database. Is there a way to ignore this exception wherever in the code this gets raised and continue with execution of code. Some way to override the exception class, so that it does nothing, i.e. the exception is suppressed.

Comment: Maybe the top answer on this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841377/rescue-from-actioncontrollerroutingerror-in-rails-4/25842118#25842118

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you want to make all models readonly, but then be able to modify and save them?

Comment: @wiesion I want to create a read only version of my application (specifically admin). A lengthy way could be to use some kind of authorization gem, but a shorter way could be to just make all models read only. I want those writes to fail silently so that the code execution isn't hindered due to the raised exceptions and the application works normally (except the writes not happening).

Comment: @ldeld no that will not help as that's just a catch all. After the exception is raised, the code after that line isn't executed. I want to suppress a specific type of exception so that the code after it is executed normally even if that exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making all your models read-only, you can try something like this:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_commit do
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, 'Read-only'
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this raise an exception and I would still get a 5xx response? I want the code execution to continue even after the write to DB fails.

Comment: @amit_saxena This callback will cancel the transaction, the exception will not be re-raised

Comment: Looks like `before_commit` isn't an available callback. I get the following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `before_commit' for ApplicationRecord(abstract):Class`. But this is an interesting approach - I believe if I override `before_save` and `before_destroy` in a similar way, it should work for 99% of the cases (unless there are some raw queries in the app and if someone is using methods which skip callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that

- All your models inherit from a custom `ApplicationRecord`
- You make use of validations
- All the interfaces accessible through URL to your models don't skip validations
- You want to use exactly the same source code for your read-only version

i suggest that you work with a global validation, which checks for the presence of an environment variable, let's call it `MY_APP_IS_READ_ONLY`:

`application_record.rb`

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your code ...
  validates :not_read_only_mode
  def not_read_only_mode
    errors.add(:base, "App runs in read-only mode") unless ENV['MY_APP_IS_READ_ONLY'].nil?
  end
```

Now all of the inherited models should fail the validation and on a failed `.save` they get redirected to the same URL (depending on your code), never being able to create or update any record. Also by specifying `:base` as the error source, you create a generic error message which is not tied to any field.

However, if you have models that NEED to be updated (session? user for last login?), you should create a separate class holding this validation and make the conditionally read-only models inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could rescue the exception in your application controller and just ignore it.